# Is it an open problem whether it is provable in Predicative Arithmetic that every natural number is a sum of four squares

Tags: number-theory, logic

I was just wondering whether it is currently an open problem whether or not it is provable in $I\Delta_0+\Omega_1$, the theory studied in Edward Nelson's book "Predicative Arithmetic", that every natural number is a sum of four squares. The proof given in Rose's "A Course in Number Theory" seems to require $EFA$.